# Problem using biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to write an essay for university using LaTeX and BibLaTeX but it's my first time using it so I think I may have messed up somewhere as I can't find any real beginner's guide!

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@ONLINE
    {arstechnica,
    AUTHOR = "Jon Brodkin",
    TITLE = "{Yahoo IP lawsuit: We patented “Facebook’s entire social network model}”,
    URL = "http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2012/03/yahoo-patent-lawsuit-we-invented-facebooks-entire-social-network-model/",
    URLYEAR = 2012
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\cite{arstechnica}

*(text...)*

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output for the text looks correct but trying the references looks like [**arstechnia** ] and the errors are:

```
Package biblatex Error: File 'positionpaper.bbl' not created by biblatex \begin{document}
Citation 'arstechnica' on page 1 undefined
Empty bibliography
There were undefined references.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) positionpaper(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Basically your example is ok. But as the log-file says, you need to run biber after the compilation with latex. But better use braces instead of quotes around the values in bib-file. And add encoding information like inputenc to your document so that biblatex and biber know the encoding of the bib-file.